# How to install Wamp server 2.5?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have installed WAMP 2.5 on my 32 bit OS windows-7 , before installation i have also installed vcredist_x86. but after the installation when i go to php extension from wamp i get this(see below images) kind of error symbol, i didn't understand what is the actual problem, this also occurs for apache modules

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to install new wamp with different port number

Answer (score 0):

The no-entry symbols indicate that either :

1. You have a extension in php.ini or LoadModule in httpd.conf but there is not actual extension or module to load in the \ext or \modules folder
2. Or you have an extension or module in the \ext or \modules folder but no entry in the php.ini or httpd.conf